# Magento: Observer method getCustomer() is NULL

Tags: magento, extension-methods

Okay so I have an observer that is observing the `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost` action. My issue is that in the method I try to do the following:

```
public function customerSaveAfter($observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
}
```

No matter what I do $customer is NULL. There is another extension that is called right before this and it uses that method exactly the same way and comes up with a customer. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer object is blank because the `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost` event is a controller action event, and has nothing to do with the customer object.   That event is issued in the following code

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php
public function postDispatch()
{
    if ($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH)) {
        return;
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName(),
        array('controller_action'=>$this)
    );
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
        array('controller_action'=>$this)
    );
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_postdispatch', array('controller_action'=>$this));
}
```

Specifically, the

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
    array('controller_action'=>$this)
);
```

bit.  (`$this->getRequest()->getRouteName()` returns `customer_account_createpost`).  Notice that

```
array('controller_action'=>$this)
```

is passed into the event dispatch — this means you could access the controller object from your observer with the following

```
$observer->getControllerAction();
$observer->getData('controller_action');
```

You can also get a list of data keys variable to an observer with

```
var_dump(
    array_keys($observer->getData())
);
```

The "other extension" (by which I assume you mean another extension's observer object) is probably listening to a different event, one that passes in a `customer` object to the event.  For example, consider the `customer_login` event.

```
#File: app/code/core/Customer/Model/Session.php
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Here the event dispatch includes a customer object

```
array('customer'=>$customer)
```

which means the customer will be available in your observer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Using this I was able to get the information I required and you were spot on with everything. Thanks!